# Uncaught TypeError: Object function has no method 'split'

Tags: javascript, jquery

No errors in the console are present, though the function does not seem to be adding the dashes like it is intended to do. Also, the code creates formatting problems on the site meaning something is wrong with this.

Code:

```
    $('#Inventory_accountNumber').blur(function(){
        var accounts = $(this).val;
        var accountsNum = [];
        accountNum = accounts.split(",");
        for(var i=0;i<accountNum.length;i++) {
            var newstr = '';
            if(accountNum[i].length == 24) {
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(0,4) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(4,7) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(7,10) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(10,14) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(14,20) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(20,24) + '-';
                newstr += '0000-000';
                accountNum[i] = newstr;
            }
            else if(accountNum[i].length == 32) {
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(0,4) + '-'
;               newstr += accountNum[i].substring(4,7) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(7,10) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(10,14) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(14,20) + '-';
                newstr += accountNum[i].substring(20,24) + '-';
                newstr += '0000-000';
                accountNum[i] = newstr;
            }
        }
        accountNum.join(',');
        $(this).val = accountNum;

    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwv4U/6/)

Comment: `var accounts = $(this).val;` -> `var accounts = $(this).val();`

Comment: also, `$(this).val = accountNum;` -> `$(this).val(accountNum);`

Comment: is `accountsNum` (plural) on line 3 a typo? Every other reference is to `accountNum` (singular).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in local code.

Comment: @Mathletics this is not off-topic, this typo was causing an error, yes, but this is still not working correctly, and no errors are being displayed.

Comment: Question edited to reflect the actual problem, instead of highlighting syntax errors.

Comment: Please describe "not functioning correctly." What does it do vs what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Mathletics It doesn't do the intended function of adding dashes if the string length is a specified length.

Comment: Well your test string is only 31 characters.

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, the code blocks for `24` and `32` characters are identical.

Comment: @Mathletics Yes, they are identical in the example code, but the live version is different. It seems this is working if the string length is changed to 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your culprit:

```
var accounts = $(this).val;
```

That should read:

```
var accounts = $(this).val();
```

What you have there is a function reference, not the value of the function's return statement.

Comment: There was another spot that had this issue as well and I fixed that too. This does not seem to be adding any dashes to the value (when removing dashes and testing). The live version of this code also now has display issues, which means something is still wrong with this code, though the console isn't reporting any.

Answer (score 1):

```
var accounts = $(this).val();
```

or

```
var accounts = $(this);
accountNum = accounts.val().split(",");
```

If you try to debug or print in your console.. an inputselector.val prints out the whole function

Also, down below

$(this).val = accountNum; is the wrong way of setting the value, use `$(this).val(accountNum);`